# Get $_POST Array before sending the form

Tags: javascript, php, var-dump

Situation:

```
<form method='post' action='troll.php'>
    <input type='text' name='trolltext'>
    <textarea name='trollarea'></textarea>
    <input type='hidden' name='trollhidden'>
    <select name='trollselect'>
        <option value='troll1'>
        ...
    </select>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

I want to var dump the $_POST array BEFORE sending to troll.php, for example, in javascript console.log. I want to see one array, no every single variables.

Comment: There is no post prior to sending. If you want to see the values of your form try serializing it using jQuery and logging that to your console

Comment: I fail to see what this has to do with PHP.

Comment: At least show what's you've tried so far.

Comment: I like your input names, very funny.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can't execute PHP before executing PHP. Use your browser's debugger and some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all inputs and store their values in an array using javascript/jQuery in the client side (NO PHP):

```
var inputs=[];
$("form :input").each(function(){
  var input = $(this); // This is the jquery object of the input, do what you will
 inputs.push(input.val());
});
console.log(inputs);//your array
```